# OSError on Python Pickle Dump

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, pickle

- I am programming a software that should be capable of making saveable flashcards for students.
- Using Python Pickle dump to save
- Error - OSError: [Errno 30] Read-only file system:
- Using Mac OS Catalina
- Using Tkinter

**Code**

```
from tkinter import *
import pickle
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

# ------------------variables--------------------------------------------
backgroundColour = '#e3e6e4'

try:
    oldNames = pickle.load(open("Card1Saves.dat", "rb"))
    print("\nold names = ", oldNames)
except FileNotFoundError:
    pass


# ------------------sub routines------------------------------------

def MakeCard():
    card1 = []
    frontTextSave = ""
    backTextSave = ""
    inputWindow = Toplevel()
    inputWindow.geometry("600x480")
    inputWindow.title("Making Flashcards....")
    inputWindow.configure(bg=backgroundColour)

    def Confirm():
       frontTextSave = frontEntry.get("1.0", END)
       backTextSave = backEntry.get("1.0", END)
       card1.append(frontTextSave)
       card1.append(backTextSave)
       pickle.dump(card1, open("Card1Saves.dat", "wb"))

       inputWindow.destroy()

    Text1 = Label(inputWindow, text="Front").place(x=0, y=0, height=50, width=50)
    frontEntry = Text(inputWindow)
    frontEntry.place(x=0, y=50, width=600, height=100)
    Text2 = Label(inputWindow, text="Back").place(x=0, y=150, height=50, width=50)
    backEntry = Text(inputWindow)
    backEntry.place(x=0, y=200, width=600, height=100)
    confirmButton = Button(inputWindow, text="CONFIRM", command=Confirm).place(x=0,     y=300, height=50, width=100)


# -------------------window-------------------------------------------


window = Tk()
window.title("Flash Cards For Me :D")
window.geometry("1000x800")
window.configure(bg=backgroundColour)
# --------------------declaration of buttons, labels etc------------------------------------
additionButtonImage =     Image.open('/Users/master.JFisher/Desktop/FlashCardsForMe/plus-button.png')
additionButtonImage = additionButtonImage.resize((100, 100), Image.ANTIALIAS)
tkImage = ImageTk.PhotoImage(master=window, image=additionButtonImage)
additionButton = Button(window, image=tkImage, anchor=NW, command=MakeCard)
# creates button
# ---------------------prop onto window----------------------------------------
additionButton.pack(anchor=NE)


window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Which line fails - include the traceback. it says "Read-only file system:". Can this be duplicated by a one line `open("test file on same file systems", 'w")`? It doesn't seem like this has anythnig to do with your code. It seems like you have a read only file system.

Answer (score 0):

You open(Card1Saves.dat", "rb"), but then you never close the file. When you use open, unless you do a " while open() as file:" it is your responsibility to then close that file, which you never do. This is likely, if I had to guess what is causing issues, as you later try to open that same file to write to it when the button is pressed.